# PHP: Json Get individual data

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get all Employee Name from my JSON Data.

This is my JSON Data

```
[ { "0"              : "65"
  , "id"             : "65"
  , "1"              : "etertet"
  , "employee_name"  : "etertet"
  , "2"              : "1"
  , "employee_salary": "1"
  , "3"              : "2"
  , "employee_age"   : "2"
  } 
]
```

This is my function of my JSON:

```
function get_employees($id=0)
  {
    global $connection;
    $query="SELECT * FROM employee";
    if($id != 0)
      {
        $query.=" WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
      }
    $response=array();
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $response[]=$row;
      }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
```

This is my code to get JSON Data

```
<?php
  # An HTTP GET request example

  $url = 'http://localhost/cloud/v1/employees';
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  //echo $data;
  $obj = json_decode($data);
  echo $obj->employee_name;
?>
```

But I am getting the error below:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cloud\v1\get.php on line 14**

Thank you

Comment: can you show json data

Comment: Hi @DevsiOdedra. JSON Data is above image. Thank you

Comment: i mean can u post same in code here.

Comment: Hi @DevsiOdedra, I have added the code. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can access as below**

```
$ar = '[{"0":"65","id":"65","1":"etertet","employee_name":"etertet","2":"1","employee_salary":"1","3":"2","employee_age":"2"}]
';



$data = json_decode($ar);

echo  $data[0]->employee_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the array in the JSON to get all the names:

```
foreach ($obj as $emp) {
    echo $emp->employee_name . "<br>";
}
```