# unable to get data from json in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have a json that is of the following structure:

```
{
  "data":{
    .   .   .
    .   .   .
    .   .   .
  },
  "meta":{
    .   .   .
    .   .   .
    .   .   .
  },
  "included":[
    {
      .   .   .
      .   .   .
    },
    { .   .   . },
    { .   .   . },
    { .   .   . },
    .   .   .   .
    {
      "unwanted":{
        .   .   .
      },
      "unwanted2":{ .   .   . },
      .    .    .    .
      "wanted1":"v1"
      "wanted2":{
        "k1":"v2",
        "k2":"v3"
      },
      "wanted3":[
        "v4",
        "v5",
        "v6"
      ],
    },
    { .   .   .},
    .   .   .   .
  ],
}
```

What I want is to get all the wanted things. Now first I tried output the following:

```
$JSON = json_decode($data, true);
echo $myJSON['included'];
```

Now this outputs "array" showing that this is an array. I then tried:

```
echo $myJSON['included']['wanted1'];
```

which shows no index named "wanted1". I figured since all the wanted stuff is in 17th element inside included so I decided to do this:

```
$i=1;
foreach( $myJSON['included'] as $item ){
    if($i==17){
        echo $item['wanted1'].PHP_EOL;
    };
    $i=$i+1
};
```

Now this also shows the same error. I do not know how to parse this. I am new to php please help.

**Edit:**
[Here is a link to json file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15PkkC1NyhxLpb3PXhvoAzdjXED6HrAFI)
What I want is "foundedOn", "Specialities","name".

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260457/6309457

Comment: I tried using this: `echo $myJSON['included'][16]->wanted1;`. It shows 
`Trying to get property 'wanted1' of non-object`

Comment: first of all you should validate your json, because current is invalid,

Comment: I have already done that by copy pasting it in an online validator and formatter. Also if u want I can share the json here. The json is actually the output of a company data in linkedin.

Answer (score 1):

If you echo $myJSON['included'][16] and get "Trying to get property 'wanted1' of non-object"
then you actually can access the variable with $myJSON['included'][16]['wanted1']

Note
if you use PHP json_decode($data, true)
it will turn your data into PHP array form

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Ok so with true in json decode the returned answer is an array so we have to access elements like array not as key, values right?